# g++ not linking wayland methods

Tags: c++, wayland

I was trying to create a Wayland window, and I keep getting these strange linkers errors.

> Header:

```
#include <wayland-client.h>
#include <wayland-client-protocol.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace dmaf
{

        class WINDOW
        {

        private:
                bool Init();

        public:
                void Run();

                WINDOW();
                ~WINDOW();

        };

        WINDOW::WINDOW()
        {
        }

        WINDOW::~WINDOW()
        {
        }

        bool WINDOW::Init()
        {

                return 1;

        }

        void WINDOW::Run()
        {

                if (Init())
                {

                        wl_display* display = wl_display_connect(0);

                        if (display)
                                printf("h\n");
                        else
                                printf("g\n");

                        if (!display)
                                return;

                        wl_display_disconnect(display);

                }

        }

}
```

> Main:

```
#include "WAYDMAF.h"
using namespace dmaf;

int main()
{

        WINDOW window;
        window.Run();

}
```

> Errors:

```
Package wayland-client-protocol was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `wayland-client-protocol.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'wayland-client-protocol' found
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccImUDBz.o: in function `dmaf::WINDOW::Run()':
dmaf_program.cxx:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `wl_display_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: dmaf_program.cxx:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `wl_display_disconnect'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

> Hello Wayland (more below)

```
@pop-os: gcc hello_wayland.c helpers.c helpers.h $(pkg-config --cflags --libs=lwayland-client) -o hello_wayland

Must specify package names on the command line
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: warning: relocation against `wl_surface_interface' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVVuR6n.o: in function `main':
hello_wayland.c:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `wl_display_dispatch'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_display_get_registry':
helpers.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `wl_registry_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_registry_add_listener':
helpers.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_add_listener'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_registry_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_registry_bind':
helpers.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor_versioned'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_compositor_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_compositor_create_surface':
helpers.c:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `wl_surface_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shm_pool_set_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_set_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shm_pool_get_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_get_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shm_pool_create_buffer':
helpers.c:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to `wl_buffer_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shm_pool_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shm_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shm_create_pool':
helpers.c:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `wl_shm_pool_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x25b): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_buffer_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_get_shell_surface':
helpers.c:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `wl_shell_surface_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x2ea): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_surface_add_listener':
helpers.c:(.text+0x31f): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_add_listener'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_surface_set_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_set_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_surface_get_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x35f): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_get_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_surface_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x379): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_surface_pong':
helpers.c:(.text+0x3a4): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_shell_surface_set_toplevel':
helpers.c:(.text+0x3c9): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_surface_set_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x3ef): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_set_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_surface_get_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x40a): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_get_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_surface_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x42e): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x43a): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_surface_attach':
helpers.c:(.text+0x476): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_surface_commit':
helpers.c:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_seat_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x4b6): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_seat_get_pointer':
helpers.c:(.text+0x4d5): undefined reference to `wl_pointer_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal_constructor'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_pointer_add_listener':
helpers.c:(.text+0x51c): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_add_listener'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_pointer_set_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x541): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_set_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_pointer_get_user_data':
helpers.c:(.text+0x55c): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_get_user_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_pointer_destroy':
helpers.c:(.text+0x576): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_destroy'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `wl_pointer_set_cursor':
helpers.c:(.text+0x5bc): undefined reference to `wl_proxy_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `hello_setup_wayland':
helpers.c:(.text+0x5d5): undefined reference to `wl_display_connect'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x638): undefined reference to `wl_display_roundtrip'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `hello_cleanup_wayland':
helpers.c:(.text+0x6a9): undefined reference to `wl_display_disconnect'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccx8fSIO.o: in function `registry_global':
helpers.c:(.text+0x6d2): undefined reference to `wl_compositor_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x704): undefined reference to `wl_compositor_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x71f): undefined reference to `wl_shm_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x74c): undefined reference to `wl_shm_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x767): undefined reference to `wl_shell_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x794): undefined reference to `wl_shell_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x7ac): undefined reference to `wl_seat_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: helpers.c:(.text+0x7de): undefined reference to `wl_seat_interface'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*^there may be some errors as I didn't try to add all necessary headers^*

I've tried a few g++ settings, but nothing.

> g++:

```
g++ program.cxx $(pkg-config --cflags wayland-client-protocol) -o program
g++ program.cxx $(pkg-config --cflags wayland-client) -o program
```

> usr/include:

```
wayland-egl
wayland-server-protocol
wayland-client
wayland-server-core
wayland-util
wayland-version
wayland-egl-core
wayland-cursor
wayland-client-protocol
wayland-server
wayland-client-core
```

I've also tried compiling Hello-Wayland, but I got a mountain of the same errors. I'm using Pop!_os, and I don't remember having any problems with X when I was on Ubuntu (Haven't tried X on Pop,and I don't remember using Wayland on Ubuntu).
It seems to only do this to wl_display_connect, wl_display_disconnect, and wl_display_connect_to_fd, so I checked in all of my header files and none of them had wl_display_connect (didn't try the other methods). Is it possible I need some other header files? If so, what do I need?

-Thanks del

Answer (score 1):

Just a small syntax error in your original g++ command:

```sh
pkg-config --cflags --libs=lwayland-client
> pkgconf: option doesn't take an argument -- libs
```

The correct syntax is the following:

```sh
pkg-config --cflags --libs wayland-client
> -lwayland-client
```

A simple g++ command to compile a file and link against `libwayland-client.so` would therefore be:

```sh
g++ waylandapp.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs wayland-client) -o waylandapp
```

which will actually turn into

```sh
g++ waylandapp.c -lwayland-client -o waylandapp
```

`-l` is a universal c/c++ linker flag, for linking libraries.
To learn more about how to use `pkg-config`, `man pkgconf` will help.