# Linking C++ Wayland application with g++ not possible?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, wayland

I am trying to link a Wayland C++ application with g++ and got stuck. It should be possible to link to the Wayland libraries from C++ since the headers (*wayland-core.h*, *wayland-client.h* etc.) correctly put the API calls into an `extern "C"` scope.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Wayland is enabled and all libraries are installed:

```sh
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get install libwayland-client0 libwayland-dev libdrm-dev
 $ sudo apt-get install wayland-protocols
```

I can compile a simple program that connects to the `wl_display` singleton but linking is not possible:

```sh
 $ pkg-config --cflags --libs wayland-client
 -lwayland-client
 $ pkg-config --variable=libdir wayland-client
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
 $ g++ -std=c++17 -pthread -Wall -lwayland-client -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o hello hello.cpp
 hello.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `wl_display_connect'
 /usr/bin/ld: hello.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `wl_display_disconnect'
```

There is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170981/g-not-linking-wayland-methods) but they are linking a C program which works on my system too. Is it not possible to link C++ for some reason?

Thank you.

Comment: The order of the link options matter. Try putting `-lwayland-client` at the end of the command.

Comment: Only an idea: Have wayland headers also forget to have C++ guards like `extern "C" {}`? There is so much fully broken with wayland...

Comment: @Klaus See above. Yes.

Comment: Ubs.. sorry, to fast, to early, lack of coffee ?? :-)

Comment: @kaylum Played with the position of `-lwayland-client` but still no luck.

Comment: Also tried on my system with `pkg-config`. Even if I also have installed all and everything for wayland development, pkg-config reports an empty list for flags AND libs. As said: I have only very bad experience with wayland. Starts by such things like your question and end up by all the missing features like touch screen calibration or multiple multi touch support, pure remote session functionality, safety aspects... In fact: We only use X11 for production! It is much to early to go with wayland, even if the project has decades in history :-)

Comment: @AndreasSpindler if it was linked correctly, let check the symbol in wayland library  `nm -gD  <path to waylan.so> | grep wl_display_disconnect`

Comment: @long.kl This is the strange part. In */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so* all functions are listed, including of course `wl_display_connect` and `wl_display_disconnect`.

Comment: @AndreasSpindler maybe like Klaus said, extern "C" didn't work. you can verify it with `g++ -std=c++17 -pthread -Wall -lwayland-client -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -c -o hello.o hello.cpp  && nm hello.o ` to see what g++ did with the hello.cpp. to verity   `wl_display_disconnect` is demangled or not .

Comment: Fixed it. This works: `g++ -o hello hello.cpp -lwayland-client`. The trick is to put `-l` last.  Using gcc 9.4 btw.

Comment: Besides removing unnecessary options do you now agree that it is the order of the link options that matter here?

Comment: @kaylum The options are not unnecessary for me (except maybe `-L`). I just removed them for clarity. I agree that the link options matter but I was not aware that `-l` has to come after `-o`.

Comment: It doesn't have to come after `-o`. It has to come after the object(s) that uses it. So in your case after `hello.cpp`. For example, this should still work `g++ hello.cpp -lwayland-client -o hello`. See the duplicate post for more details.

Comment: @kalym Yes. It does. Thank you. Haven't wrote a plain cc call for a while and used to much cmake I guess.